# I am not sure what ctypes.py_objects does exactly

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I am reading through [DSA in python](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=dnVrbWFsYmFzYS5jb218d3d3fGd4OjU3NWZjOWU1MTM4ZTI4OQ). It is a bit above my comprehension as of now. But the central questions is what does [ctypes.py_object](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject) do. I see that it makes a pointer but when instantiated and printed but, it doesn't bring back an array like I would like to see just the pointer. Specifically, I want some insight on the "make_array" method. How could I make a proper array? What is the visualization of _A variable?

```
import ctypes
class DynamicArray:
    def __init__(self):
        self._n=0
        self._capacity=1
        self._A=self._make_array(self._capacity)
    def __len__(self):
        return self._n
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if not 0<= k < self._n:
            raise IndexError('INVALID INDEX')
        return self._A[k]
    def append(self,obj):
        if self._n==self._capacity:
            self._resize(2*self._capacity)
        self._A[self._n]=obj
        self._n+=1
    def _resize(self,c):
        B=self._make_array(c)
        for k in range(self._n):
            B[k]=self._A[k]
        self._A=B
        self._capacity=c
    def _make_array(self,c):            
        return (c*ctypes.py_object)()
```

I was expecting variable _A (in the init method) to be an array of the capacity's length.
Which I then could add elements through the append method.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're encountering with this code?  The ctypes array object you create doesn't have a particularly useful string representation - but it should work just fine for the purposes you're using it for.

Comment: `ctypes` is used to interface to C code.  `py_object` is the type of any Python object and is the type used to pass to a C function that takes a `PyObject*` as a parameter, or returns a `PyObject*` as a return value.  If you aren't interfacing to C code it is just a slower way to handle Python objects.

Comment: @jasonharper the code works I was just having difficulties figuring out what ctypes.py_object would do exactly. The documentation of it was pretty weak IMO

Comment: @MarkTolonen Gotcha almost like its own encapsulation for objects. It'll take the parameters of make a container of 'x' values